# Importing WebKit causes application to fail at start-up.

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygtk, canonical-quickly

I'm making an application using Quickly, and I want to add a Webkit widget to my window.
I thought "Should be easy enough", but as always, it couldn't be that easy.

From the moment I add `import webkit`, the application fails to start.

```
robin@RobinJ:~/Ubuntu One/Python/gtkreddit$ quickly run
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type `PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's `GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
```

The entire source code can be found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/gtkreddit/trunk/files). The specific file I'm talking about, is [this one](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~robinj/gtkreddit/trunk/view/head:/gtkreddit/GtkredditWindow.py).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are mixing bindings. If you are already using GObject Introspection, then stay with that. Try:

```
from gi.repository import WebKit
```

or use the old bindings for GTK (pygtk).